# DataGridView Loading From LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a form with DataGridViews that have the DataSource set to a DataContext of my database to auto pull in the info and allow it to be edited. But I need a color to display a Color from the color id that corresponds to a color in a colors table and I don't know how I can achieve this with also allowing it to auto edit and update the records.

```cs
private dbCounterTopsDataContext dbContext = new dbCounterTopsDataContext();

private void FrmCurrentInventory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridColors.DataSource = dbContext.Colors;
    dataGridBarTops.DataSource = dbContext.BarTops;
    dataGridKitchenTops.DataSource = dbContext.Kitchens;
    dataGridVanityTops.DataSource = dbContext.Vanities;
}
```

I have also tried this and it worked with displaying but I could no longer update directly from the datagrid

```cs
private void FrmCurrentInventory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridColors.DataSource = dbContext.Colors.Select(o => new { ColorId = o.ColorID, Color = o.Color1 });
    dataGridBarTops.DataSource = dbContext.BarTops.Select(o => new { Color = o.Color.Color1, Length = o.Length, Width = o.Width });
    dataGridKitchenTops.DataSource = dbContext.Kitchens.Select(o => new { Color = o.Color.Color1, Length = o.Length }).ToList();
    dataGridVanityTops.DataSource = dbContext.Vanities;
}
```

Comment: Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and set the `.Columns` collection manually with the columns you want to display. The other columns will still exist in the `.DataSource` but won't be displayed

Comment: I understand that but lets say I pull a bartop and it has a color id of 5 in the colors table the id 5 is blue how would i get it to display blue instead of 5 and still be editable

Comment: I _think_ you could possibly use a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to achieve this. The `DisplayMember` would be the name of the color, the `ValueMember` would be its numerical ID

Comment: @SSS you'd be right, but you missed a vital advice - setting the DataPropertyName of the combo is essential

Comment: @CaiusJard that's correct, and the datasource of the combobox should be set to the colors

Answer (score 1):

Some good tips in the comments from SSS, perhaps the easiest way to get this going is to use AutogenerateColumns to gen most of the stuff and then add a few combo box columns for your colors. It would probably go something like this:

```
dataGridColors.DataSource = 

dataGridBarTops.DataSource = dbContext.BarTops;
dataGridBarTops.AutogenerateColumns = false;
var c = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
c.HeaderText = "Color";
c.DisplayMember = "Color1"; //name of property that says Blue in color entity
c.ValueMember = "ColorID"; //name of property that says 5 in color/entity
c.DataPropertyName = "BarTopColorId"; //name of property that says 5 in BARTOPS table/entity
c.DataSource = dbContext.Colors; //personally I would use a bindingSource here
dataGridBarTops.Columns.Add(cb);
```

I'll leave removing the text box color is column as an exercise for you- maybe leave it in first to see how combo is working

The Colors datagridview is for editing the actual Colors definitions etc. The combo box in the bar top table is for choosing a different color is for a single bar top. If you edit the Colors table it will change what is in the list of the combo. If you pick a new combo value it will change the bartop's color id (whatever that property is called) value

Be careful not to edit away ids in Colors that are used in bartops - don't delete color Id 5 from the Colors table while there is still a bartop that uses it

---

I put a comment there about bindingsources. I've never bound a DGV straight to a LINQ entity list, nor probably would I (partly because it's downloading an entire table, which could be huge and partly because my winforms databinding is near exclusively with strongly typed datasets) but you find it to work (and maybe you need the whole table, no filtering). If, however you start to see strange effects like selecting different rows in the Colors datagridview causes all the combo boxes to change value, bind the combo through a bindingsource so they have something that dedicatedly tracks "the current item" for the combo

Comment: dgv binding to LINQ doesn't work well out of the box, you need to use a third-party library like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView/1.4.5222.35545?_src=template

Comment: dgv works best with classic ADO.NET `DataTables` imo

Comment: Good tips. Reading the abstract of the nuget package I'm not sure what that lib does that a BindingSource doesn't - any idea?

Comment: AFAICT it's an alternative to coding up a custom `BindingSource`. I don't use binding for UPDATE operations in my own code, so if the OP wants a read/write dgv they might be better off implementing a `BindingSource`