# DataGridViewComboboxCell display member not showing up

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, dataview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

### Goal

A datagridview of *SteelTypes* has a column that has been bound to a dataview (*SteelThicknesses*). I can select the data and set it correctly. However I cannot load the same information. My datagridview comboboxcell contains the value and editted formatted text but I cannot set the display member information.

### Current problem

I have all of my textbox columns loading correctly except the combobox column. The variable of **cbCol** is set correctly and the EditedFormattedValue and FormattedValue contain the value I want! However the displayMember does not get replicated into the datagridviewcombobox cell.

I am trying to display a "3" into the Épaisseur (thickness) column via setting its value to a primary key (PK_SteelThickness):

[image]

See the results below. Everything except my comboboxcell is populated:
[image]

Appreciate the help in advance, this has gotten me crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd behavior but I found that changing my loading method calls from the new() to the form Load() made it work...

So I changed my initial code from this:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    LoadSteelPlates()
    LoadPlateQuotes()
End Sub
```

To this:

```
Private Sub frmQuotePads_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadSteelPlates()
    LoadPlateQuotes()
End Sub
```

This is the only code that was modified and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

You don't set the text. You set the underlying ID. The idea is that you bind the column to a parent table and you bind the grid to a child table that has a foreign key to that parent table. You set the foreign key value in the grid cell and the corresponding text value from the parent table gets displayed.

As an example, let's say that you have a `Handedness` table like so:

```
Id Name
 1 Right
 2 Left
 3 Ambidextrous
```

and you have a `Person` table like so:

```
Id Name  HandednessId
 1 Peter            2
 2 Paul             1
 3 Mary             3
```

In your grid you would create a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and set its `DataPropertyName` property to "HandednessId". When you then bound your `Person` table to the grid, the `HandednessId` column would bind to the combo box column. You would bind your `Handedness` table to the column and set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to "Name" and "Id" respectively. The grid would then display "Left", "Right" and "Ambidextrous" for "Peter", "Paul" and "Mary" respectively. If you wanted to make Peter ambidextrous, you would set the `HandednessId` cell `Value` to 3 and then it would display "Ambidextrous".

See this for more information:

[Adding a ComboBox Column to a DataGridView](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had looked at your answer on VBForums as well. I actually do have the display member and value member set on the DataGridViewComboboxCell. It has the proper value that was set on the ValueMember to the correct ID that I specified. However it doesn't display the display member. Yet in the EdittedFormatValue I can see that it shows the right information to display but it doesn't appear on the screen

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're making a lot of work for yourself here. Datagridcombobox can be used to decode a value simply by having its

- DataSource set to something that provides the key/value lookup, for example a SteelThicknesses datatable with two columns Disp and Val and has rows like `"Thick",1` `"Medium", 2` `"Thin", 3`,
- DisplayMember set to a string of the column name from the lookup table that contains the text to show, for example "Disp",
- ValueMember set to the string column name from the lookup that has the value that relates to the text to show, for example "Val" and
- DataPropertyName set to the name of the property(column) in the other table that has the value to be decoded (one of the values in the Val column of the lookup table) (for example a Products table with a SteelThicknessID column).

The datagridview is bound to the products datatable, the combo will find e.g. 3 in the steelthicknessid column, it will look 3 up in the Val column of the steelthicknesses table and show the text it finds in the Disp column of that row from steelthickesses.if the user changes the value shown by dropping the combo list and picking Thick, it will work the reverse and take 1 from the Val column and update the products table with the new value 1 for steelthicknessid. If you don't want that, make the column or datagridview read only

For a more involved discussion see my answer in [DataGridView Loading From LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61535840/datagridview-loading-from-linq?noredirect=1#comment108933951_61535840)